# Elasticsearch - Unique counts of a field, filter by the number of documents that contain a specific value in an other field

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm trying to do  kind of a complex search but I can't found how to do it, or even if it's possible.

I use Elasticsearch to store document.
All of this document have a `userId` field which is potentially the **same** in multiple documents. 
They also have a `documentType` field which contains a string.

I want to have a unique count of userId that have at least `n` number of a DocumentType.

Currently if `n = 1` I'm able to retrieve the unique count with this request:

```
{ 
"aggs": {
    "docType_file": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "documentType:\"file\"": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "documentType:\"file\"",
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_user": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "userId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I want `n` to be superior to 1 (or if I want to do an other operation, less, equal or range) I don't find a way to do it. I have look in the different aggregations but I don't find how to combine them to retrieve this.

Is it possible to do that in Elasticsearch?

**UPDATE:**

I found an other way to do the query which may be more interesting to do an other aggregations afterward.

```
{          
"query": {                    
    "filtered": { 
      "query": {    
        "query_string": {                
          "query": "documentType:\"file\""
        }                                             
      }                                 
    }              
  },           
  "aggs": {
    "unique_user": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "userId", 
        "precision_threshold": 40000
      }                 
    }                     
  }                                                              
}
```

But I still don't know how to filter after that and I kind of think that I'm taking the problem the wrong way but I don't see any other solution.

Comment: the following question is kind of related: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038916/unique-counts-of-a-field-columns-split-by-the-number-of-documents-that-contain)